# How do I declare a type variable that extends a Parameterised type?

Tags: java, generics

I'm not much of a Java programmer so excuse me if my terminology is a bit off. I'd like to declare the following:

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar<I, J, K>> {
    ....
};
```

My IDE tells me that it can't resolve I, J or K.

Is what I'm trying to do possibly in Java or should I take some other approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare all the type parameters :

```
public class Foo<I,J,K,T extends Bar<I, J, K>> {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare them implicitly this way, you need to write

```
public class Foo<I, J, K, T extends Bar<I, J, K>>
```

Note if this seems redundant, you might find all you need is

```
public class Foo<I, J, K> {
     final Bar<I, J, K> bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `I,J,K` are not classes and they are type-parameter names, the compiler needs to refer into an explicit declaration of them.

This would work

```
class Foo<I,J,K,T extends Bar<I, J, K>> {

}
```

Given that `Bar` expects 3 type-params,

```
class Bar<I,J,K>{

}
```